# store kafka-streams table in data store

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I create a `KTable<Integer, CustomObject>`, and now I want to store this data from KTable to mysql db.

Is it possible to save KTable in db? I checked `Materialized` class, but I do not see appropriate method for it.

```
final KTable<Integer, Result> result =
    users_table.join(photos_table, (a, b) ->  Result.from(a, b));
```

Or it's only possible with Consumer Api? When I read from "my-results" topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Materialized` is to configure/set the store used by Kafka Streams -- if you don't have a good reason to change it, it's recommended to use the default setting.

If you want to put the data into an external DB, you should write the `KTable` into a topic `KTable#toStream#to("topic")` and use Kafka Connect to load the data from the topic into the DB.

Comment: But, instead of Connect, is it possible to use kafka consumers, right?

Comment: Yes. You can write a Java application with a consumer, read the topic and write to the DB via JDBC for example. In fact, you could even to do this with Streams API via `KTable#toStream()#foreach()`.